# How to keep list items that fall between two values

Tags: python

I would like to keep a list of items that fall between two values in the list.

Below is a representation of the list I have:

```
List = ['Waste','Waste','Start','Data','Data','End','Waste','Waste']
```

I need to keep the `'Data'` strings.

Desired result below.

```
Res = ['Start','Data','Data','End']
```

I'm currently converting the list to a string, splitting on `'Start'`, converting back to a string, and then splitting on `'End'` whilst indexing the correct side of the split I want to keep. It's messy.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Using `List` for a variable name isn't idiomatic Python. For one thing -- it begins with a capital letter but it isn't a class. See the [Style Guide for Python Programming](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `'Start'` and `'End'` elements exist, with `'Start'` occurring before `'End'`, you can use:

```
List[List.index('Start'):List.index('End')+1]
```

Comment: he needs set , So i think it should be set(List[List.index('Start')+1:List.index('End')])

Comment: @SarthakGupta the desired output is a list

Comment: OP said nothing about needing a `set()` as result.

Comment: @accdias OP *did* use the word "set" (but didn't use it precisely). Furthermore, before the edit, it wasn't clear what their intended output was.

Comment: That seems to work. Is this using List.index('Start')+1 as the starting index and List.index('End') as the end index?

Comment: Sorry, use of the word set could've made it a little unclear. Edited.